# Beautiful soup match tag content in html object to variable

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have `soup` object

```
apt_object = soup.find(string="Data about object:").find_next('ul')
```

which gives following `html`:

```
<ul>
<li>New building</li>
<li>Lift</li>
<li>City pluming</li>
<li>City sanitary</li>
</ul>
```

For various pages this will give list with predefined values defined in `li` tag.

I wan't match all values to predefined variables like
`ads_object_newBuilding` and assign "Yes" to variable if `<li>New building</li>` exists in html object or "No" if it doesn't.

I have so far solution that lists every `li` tag in `html` object and check is and than doing assignment:

```
for li in apt_object:
    if li.string.strip().find("New building"):
        ads_object_newBuilding= "Yes"
    else: ads_object_newBuilding= "No"
    if li.string.strip().find("Lift"):
        apt_object_lift = "Yes"
    else: apt_object_lift = "No"
```

I wonder if check and assignment to variable can be done in one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
apt_object = soup.find(string="Data about object:").find_next('ul').text
apt_objekt_novogradnja, apt_objekt_lift  = "No", "No"

if "New building" in apt_object:
    apt_objekt_novogradnja = "Yes"
if "Lift" in apt_object:
    apt_objekt_lift = "Yes"

print(apt_objekt_novogradnja, apt_objekt_lift)
```

Comment: Thank you! Works! :) ...I was missing .text on the end of find_next('ul').text

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ternary operator:

```
ads_object_newBuilding = "Yes" if li.string.strip().find("New building") else "No"
```